# onsubmit in Twitter Bootstrap modal doesn't get triggered

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap

The code is simple:

HTML:

```
<div class="modal dialog-add-category fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialogAddCategoryLabel">
    <form onsubmit='alert("444")'>
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h4 id="dialogAddCategoryLabel" class="modal-title">Add a category</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text" name="category_name" placeholder="Category name"/>
                    <div class="parent-category-tree"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Create</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('.dialog-add-category').modal('show');
});
```

Here's the live version: http://jsfiddle.net/ygbhousz/1/

As you can see, the form has `onsubmit` event, but it doesn't get triggered. Why is it happening and what can I do to achieve these goals:

- Esc key and Cancel button should close the modal
- Enter key and submit button should submit the form (show the alert) and then close the modal

?

Comment: it's possible that Bootstrap is swallowing other events. Have you tried using a normal button and add a custom submit function? If you want the dialog to close AFTER submission success, you'd need more bespoke work anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't use **onsubmit**, you have done a mistake over the submit button, you should remove `data-dismiss="modal"`. Then there is no function for calling event on submit, so add the code

```
$(document).on('click', '[type="submit"]', function() {

    alert('444');

});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ygbhousz/3/)

Comment: Good one. But I just added 'return false;' to the end of it to stop the form from submitting after handling the event, and now it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @z2014 you could do something like "return confirm('For real?')" to submit or abort the form depending on user feedback.